# Miniminer workflow?

Tags: workflow, editing

After using SoundMiner v4pro for years, I have put miniminer on my machine at home.  I had been in the habit of keeping a hand on the fader for the SM Engine aux track in Pro Tools. This way I can keep my monitoring levels constant without blasting myself when auditioning things like crashes and explosions.

Miniminer does not go "through" Pro Tools the way v4pro does. Therefore, the only level adjustment I have is mousing over to Miniminers Volume fader or adjusting my interface (which I don't want to do).

I haven't found anyway to assign a controller to Miniminer itself. Am I just out of luck here? Any suggestions?

Thanks, 
Chris

Answer (score 1):

Are you referring to ReWire?

What I do, and many other sound editors I work with do, is patch your computers 1/8" TRS out into our Digi box's Analog in 7-8.  Then we create an Aux input with Analog 7-8 as the In.  Then you should be able to control it just as if you had the SM ReWrie patched into an Aux.

I believe that's what you're asking?

Answer (score 0):

Thats exactly it!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I return the Mac's built in optical output to my Digi interface and move the fader in protools.